# Spring Boot/MVC. Reading an HTTP header in MessageConverter which was previously set in Controller

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, http-headers

REST Controller must adjust JSON conversion depending on some business logic result. The conversion itself happens in MessageConverter. Usually in `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`. To achive it, the controller method sets additional response header like this.

```
@GetMapping("/method")
@Override
public ResultObject method(HttpServletResponse response) {
    if (weNeedItPretty) {
        response.setHeader("X-pretty-print", "1");
    }
}
```

The MessageConverter reads the header and adjusts it's behaviour.

```
@Override
protected void writeInternal(Object o, Type t, HttpOutputMessage output) {
     HttpHeaders headers = output.getHeaders();
     List<String> header = headers.remove("X-pretty-pring");
     if (header != null && ! header.isEmpty()) {
         // do it pretty
     }
}
```

It worked with old Spring 4.0, but not working anymore with Spring Boot 2.0 (Spring 5.1.4). The HttpOutputMessage just doesn't include headers which were previously set by controller using HttpServletResponse.

One could dig for original HttpServletResponse inside the HttpOutputMessage and it works:

```
    ServletServerHttpResponse oo = (ServletServerHttpResponse)output;
    HttpServletResponse response = oo.getServletResponse();
    Collection<String> headers = response.getHeaderNames();
```

But is looks crazy. Is it maybe possible to propagate the headers from HttpServletResponse into HttpOutputMessage automatically as it was in Spring 4.0? Is it maybe a bug?

Comment: That is odd.  Maybe you could step into the getHeaders() method while debugging to see if there is a code change that impacted this functionality.  This seems like a bug to me.